# Convert integer date time into real date time problem? JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio, date, datetime, datetime-format

so I have this problem converting Integer DateTime format to normal DateTime format in Java.
I have this this variable int DateTime, for example it is : "/Date(1484956800000)/" . And i am trying to convert it to normal date time and show it to the screen ...

I tried like this..

```
   String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm")
                .format(new Date(Integer.parseInt(deals.getDate_time())  * 1000L));

// setting my textView with the string dateAsText
       holder.Time.setText(dateAsText);
```

Comment: It seems that your int/long value (1484956800000) already is a timestamp with milliseconds resolution. Try to convert it without multiplying by 1000L first.

Comment: @ThomasKläger i removed the 1000L , but the same problem..,

Comment: *the same problem* — which problem, I think you forgot to tell us? [I downvoted because without a proper and precise problem description we cannot help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one: `Integer.parseInt(deals.getDate_time())` will throw a `NumberFormatException` for 1484956800000 because 1484956800000 doesn't fit into the integer range. You must also replace it with `Long.parseLong(deals.getDate_time())`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you **stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Obtain an instance of Instant using milliseconds from the epoch of
        // 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1484956800000L);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Specify the time-zone
        ZoneId myTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        // Obtain ZonedDateTime out of Instant
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(myTimeZone);

        // Obtain LocalDateTime out of ZonedDateTime
        // Note that LocalDateTime throws away the important information of time-zone
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Custom format
        String dateAsText = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd HH:mm"));
        System.out.println(dateAsText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2017-01-21T00:00:00Z
2017-01-21T00:00
01-21 00:00
```

If you still want to use the poorly designed legacy `java.util.Date`, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(1484956800000L);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Custom format
        String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm").format(date);
        System.out.println(dateAsText);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sat Jan 21 00:00:00 GMT 2017
01-21 00:00
```